# Could you please explain "Kinesthetic Metaphor"?

Tags: metaphors, learning, psychology

My major is pure mathematics and I am reading an article on "Metaphors in preschool child thinking about the mind" for some reasons!

 I can't understand the meaning of "Kinesthetic Metaphor"; Google Search Engine was not useful!

Could you please explain it for me?

Comment: From [Strategies: A Journal for Physical and Sport Educators 
Volume 15, 2001_Moving Metaphors for Teachers and Coaches](http://tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/08924562.2001.10591512?journalCode=ustr20): << A moving or kinesthetic metaphor is an extension of a written or spoken metaphor where a designed activity is framed around a metaphor. >> So, a teaching device rather than a subset of written/spoken metaphors.

Answer (score -1):

Simply enough, they are metaphors that contain verbs of movement `(κινέω (kinéō, “I put in motion”) + αἴσθησις (-αισθησία) (aísthēsis (-aisthēsía), “sensation”)`.

So any metaphor that contains movement = kinesthetic metaphor.

Some examples:

```
walk like a duck
swim like a fish
jumping the shark
```